# How to write in gml format (using Python library Networkx) with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, networkx

What I am trying to do in this program is read from a text file (dblp dataset, to be more specific) using readline() and parse it.

I have then used Python library Networkx to construct a graph (nodes are authors, edges exist between two authors if they write a paper together and edges denote the frequency of their co-authorship) and then write the graph to a file in gml format.

The problem I am facing is, the names of authors probably have UTF-encoding. While writing to file in gml format, I get the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 
3: ordinal not in    range(128)
```

The read_gml() function in networkx has a parameter for encoding, but the write_gml() does not have one. From what I understood, write_gml() internally uses latin-1 encoding.

How can I manipulate it somehow to make it work in my case?

I tried using codecs to open the file where I want to write, but that seems to work only for write() function, but not write_gml().

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following string at the beginning of your python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```